# Convert android studio environment from kotlin to java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm still beginner in android studio ,and I'm asking if I can change the whole android studio code files from kotlin to java ?!

Comment: Nope, it's near impossible for now. You can convert it to bytecode but it won't give you any java code from it. For now, you can read the kotlin and bytecode then convert them to java by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think converting the whole project from kotlin to java isn't possible.

You can convert single Kotlin files to Java

[image]
[image: First step to convert Kotlin to Java]

Or you can convert the whole project from Java to Kotlin.

[image]

However, I would not convert anything and just stay on Kotlin.

Comment: Yes. The only reason I want to convert Kotlin to Java is understanding, where an error occured. Reading a stack trace after crash with Kotlin coroutines is very difficult.